# API request flutter app returning status code 404 not found

Tags: node.js, flutter, express

GET all and POST method via API is working fine. UPDATE API returning the status code 404.

[image]
[image]

```js
// NodeJs update method
app.post("/api/update/:id ", (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id * 1;
  let productTobeUpdate = productData.find((p) => p.id === id);
  let index = productData.indexOf(productTobeUpdate);
  productData[index] = req.body;
  res.status(200).send({
    status: "Success",
    message: "Product Updated",
  });
  print(res);
});
```

```dart
//flutter Update API
// update method
static updateProduct(id, body) async {
  var url = Uri.parse("${baseUrl}update/$id");

  final res = await http.post(url, body: body);

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    print(jsonDecode(res.body));
  } else {
    print("Failed to update");
  }
}
```

Where would be the issue?

Comment: **Just a TYPO**. You have a trailing space after `:id` in your route definition.

Comment: FYI `print()` isn't a Node.js function. Did you mean `console.log(res)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space from the `route` defination as @Phil suggested.

Change

```
app.post("/api/update/:id ", (req, res) => {
```

to

```
app.post("/api/update/:id", (req, res) => {
```